# Difference between used assembly and referenced assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-assembly

I get the following error message when trying to launch my asp.net application:

> Error 1   Assembly 'MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Http,
>   Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

What does this message mean? What is the difference between the used assembly and the referenced one?

When looking at System.Web.Http assembly's properties (via Solution Explorer -> My Project -> References -> System.Web.Http) I can see 5.2.3.0.

There is a lot of questions/answers on SO related to this kind of error but I can't find one really explaining what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that `System.Web.Http` is loaded as part of the web application initialization, long before your project reference comes to play. So by the time your project loads, it's trying to load a newer version of the same assembly into the same application domain, causing an error.

You can use an assembly binding redirect in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
      culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </runtime>
</configuration.
```